# error: no matching function for call to 'Employee::Employee()'

Tags: c++

Looked at similar threads and this doesn't show up. Basically I want chef to inherit the functions and data from employee (base class) but i'm having issues with the constructor for the derived class. I'm getting the error: no matching function for call to 'Employee::Employee()' Could someone show me how to declare my constructors for this derived class and my future derived classes for this program. Tried a bunch of things and can't seem to get it working.

```
class Employee
{
    public:
        Employee(int theempID, string thefirstName, string thelastName, char theempClass, int thesalary)
    {
        this->empID = theempID;
        this->firstName = thefirstName;
        this->lastName = thelastName;
        this->empClass = theempClass;
        this->salary = thesalary;
    };


protected:
    int empID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    char empClass;
    int salary;

};


class Chef : public Employee
{
    public:
        Chef(int theempID, string thefirstName, string thelastName, char theempClass, int thesalary, string theempCuisine) : Employee() {}
    {
        this->empID = theempID;
        this->firstName = thefirstName;
        this->lastName = thelastName;
        this->empClass = theempClass;
        this->salary = thesalary;
        this->empCuisine = theempCuisine;
    };

    string getCuisine()
    {
        return empCuisine;
    }

protected:
    string empCuisine;
};



#endif // EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employee() is trying to default construct an Employee but there is no default constructor for Employee.  Instead, construct it with the parameters your constructor it expects.

The Chef constructor should look like this:

```
Chef(int theempID, string thefirstName, string thelastName, char theempClass, int thesalary, string theempCuisine) :
    Employee(theempID, thefirstName, thelastName, theempClass, thesalary), empCuisine(theempCuisine)
    {}
```

Note the body of the constructor is empty.  The Employee base class and the member variable are **initialized** in the initialization list.  No **assignment** necessary in the body.  You should also change the base class constructor so it uses initialization instead of assignment.

Comment: Great explanation, I would up vote if I could. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: If the answer is good please accept it.  Hopefully you can do that. :)